# How to display different components for different users on one route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need to show different components in one route.

My router with authorization looks like:

```
<Route authorize={['admin']} component={Authorization}>
    <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
</Route>
```

And in `Authorization` component I have to check if the user has a access to this route.
But the question is how to show different components on the same route?

Something like this doesn't work:

```
<Route authorize={['admin']} component={Authorization}>
    <Route path='/home' component={AdminHome} />
</Route>
<Route authorize={['manager']} component={Authorization}>
    <Route path='/home' component={MangerHome} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define only one route and create a wrapper component, inside wrapper component check the condition and render different component.

Like this:

```
<Route authorize={['manager', 'admin']} component={Authorization}>
    <Route path='/home' component={WrapperComponent} />
</Route>
```

Now from `Authorization` component pass some `bool` to `WrapperComponent` to decide between which component do you want to render.

Inside `WrapperComponent`:

```
render(){
   if(this.props.isAdmin)
      return <Home  />
   return < MangerHome />
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to be a solution but if I have 3-5 roles, my Wrapper Component will look like hell.

Comment: Wrapper component is doing that job only, to make it more generic you can create a hash like `{1: Admin, 2: Manager}` and directly write inside render: `return hash[this.props.key]`, on the basis of key hash will return the component.